# specgram en mainwindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, matplotlib

Estoy generando un analizador de espectro de audio..

Ya he loggrado generar el analizador con ciertas características que necesito, sin embargo, no puedo hacer que la representación gráfica que resulta aparezca en la ventana principal, ni que el color de fondo sea negro, y de igual manera no se como arrastar cualquier archivo de audio y lo analice aqui dejo el ejemplo de lo que quiero conseguir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi codigo.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QFrame, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow. __init__(self)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('Background-color:black')
        self.frame.resize(QMainWindow.size(self))



        data, samplerate = sf.read('Close Your Eyes.flac')
        y = data.sum(axis=1)/2
        Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=256, Fs=samplerate, cmap='jet')

        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10,5)
        plt.xlim(0, len(y) / samplerate)
        plt.ylim(0, 23000)
        plt.colorbar(im).set_label('Intensidad (dB)')
        plt.xlabel('Tiempo (s)')
        plt.ylabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
        plt.show()




app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.resize(600,400)
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a ir por partes:

- Para obtener el estilo que muestras en el gráfico lo más simple es usar el estilo que viene ya predefinido en Matplotlib, [**`dark_background`**](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html). También sería posible hacerlo cambiando el color manualmente a cada elemento por supuesto.
- Para embeber el gráfico en tu aplicación de Qt lo más simple y directo es que uses el backend que proporciona matplotlib, en concreto [`matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/backend_qt5agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg). Actualmente es un widget más, por lo que puedes manejarlo como tal.
- Para permitir arrastrar y soltar los archivos a analizar debes  habilitar el *Drag and Drop* en el widget mediante el método `Qwidget.setAcceptDrops(True)` y sobreescribir el evento `dropEvent` para que cuando se suelte el archivo encima del widget se ejecute el código necesario para generar el espectrograma.

El código a modo de ejemplo podría quedar algo así:

```
import sys
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import soundfile as sf




class Spectrograph(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        plt.style.use('dark_background')

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.cbar = None
        self.compute_initial_figure()

        super(Spectrograph, self).__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/uri-list'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore() 


    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls:
            for url in e.mimeData().urls():
                e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
                e.accept()
                file = str(url.toLocalFile())
                self.update_graph(file)
        else:
            e.ignore()


    def update_graph(self, file):
        self.axes.cla()
        if self.cbar:
            self.cbar.remove()

        data, samplerate = sf.read(file)
        y = data.sum(axis=1)/2
        Pxx, freqs, bins, im = self.axes.specgram(y, NFFT=256, Fs=samplerate, cmap='jet')
        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10,5)
        self.axes.set_xlim(0, len(y) / samplerate)
        self.axes.set_ylim(0, 23000)
        self.cbar = self.fig.colorbar(im)
        self.cbar.set_label('Intensidad (dB)')
        self.axes.set_xlabel('Tiempo (s)')
        self.axes.set_ylabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
        self.a = 0
        self.draw()


    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle("Audio Spectrograph")

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.graph = Spectrograph(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.graph)

        self.main_widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:   black}")

        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> **Nota:** No he tocado la forma en la que obtienes los datos del archivo de audio y los graficas, solo se ha adaptado. Todo este procedimiento se realiza dentro del método `SpectroGraph.update_graph` en este caso.

Y este es el comportamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfecto, el unico detalle que veo es que en el espectro de audio las frecuencias que sobrepasan la frecuencia, se muestran de color verde  agua, y necesito que eso tambien se vea de color negro, para ir al grano que lo unico que se pinte de colores sean el esprectro amarillo y naragnja en este caso que serian los valores de la cancion, y el resto negro... como lo muetro en el gif.

Comment: y ahora me arroja un pequeño error  que cuando muestra la infromacion de un archivo al tratar de cargar uno nuevo no elimina el pasado y lo sobre pone...

Comment: @Revsky01 no tengo a mano ahora un pc para probar, en cuanto pueda le hecho un vistazo.  El segundo problema que dices tener es un error tonto mio, en realidad no debe sobreponer el gráfico ya que los ejes se limpian si no me equivoco, lo que si hace seguro es crear una nueva colorbar sin eliminar la anterior... He editado el código, ahora no debería pasar esto último. En cuanto a lo primero cuando pueda lo miraré a ver si doy con algo.

Comment: estabien seguimos en contacto Gracias por el apoyo